# Getting error during implementing unique user name

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I was watching this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLWHEiH1FZY

I want my Angular Firebase app with the user in such a way that no similar username repeated. But I'm getting two errors

> Argument of type '(auth: User) => any[] | AngularFireObject' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: User, index: number) => ObservableInput'.
> Type 'any[] | AngularFireObject' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.
> Type 'AngularFireObject' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.
> Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'AngularFireObject' but required in type 'Iterable'.

My code is

```
export class User {
      uid: string;
      username: string = "";
    
      constructor(auth) {
        this.uid = auth.uid
      }
}
```

Error occurs at

```
    this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(auth => {
        if (auth) {
          this.currentUser = new User(auth)  
          return this.db.object(`users/${auth.uid}`) // getting error here
        } else return [];
      })
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `switchMap` operator you need to return an observable. Try to return the `valueChanges()` method.

```js
this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap(auth => {
    if (auth) {
      this.currentUser = new User(auth);
      return this.db.object(`users/${auth.uid}`).valueChanges();   // <-- return `valueChanges()` here
    } else return of([]);      // <-- `of` method to return an observable
  })
)
```